# Output if PHP is True 1 OR Empty Condition

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I'm using a Wordpress custom field to show PHP if a value is clicked / TRUE. That's fine, but I have a vast number of custom posts and don't want to have to manually assign the true value of '1' to each one so that it works. So what I want to achieve is a fallback to also output the php if the field is currently blank / empty / nothing entered yet. So far I have:-

```
<?php
 $custom_header_visibility = get_field('custom_header_visibility');
 if( $custom_header_visibility =='1'){ ?>   
 Output here
 <?php }?>
```

so this is what I want to tag on for if set to '1' OR is empty/nothing added yet :-

```
 $custom_header_visibility == ''
```

How can I achieve that with this format please?

Thanks
Glennyboy

Comment: that depends on what get_field returns...

Comment: It would depend on what is stored in the "custom_header_visibility" field.

Comment: Feeling silly now. I just set the condition so that it was not 'false' '0'

Comment: Still interested in PHP OR operator though...

Comment: I am confused, what values can be there for `$custom_header_visibility` and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input guys. As discussed I realised that I could just reverse the logic so that it echoed the output if it didn't equal 0 (False) - which covers 1 True and also the empty fields not yet populated:-

... so line 3

```
if( $custom_header_visibility !='0'){ ?>
```